# Administrator privileges in Python

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, admin

I am trying to create a socket on python that requires administrator privileges. I keep getting this error though:

**error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

I have tried implementing solutions on this website, concluding that it is probably an administrator error. One of the most notable is the code marked as the best answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilage-on-windows). However, even after implementing it in my code, after I tell UAC to allow the elevation, I still get the same error. Any review on my code below would be much appreciated.

```
if not admin.isUserAdmin():
admin.runAsAdmin()

icmp = socket.getprotobyname("icmp")

# Create Socket
try:
    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)
```

Comment: That admin module is supposed to open a second cmd window for the elevated process - are you sure the exception happens in the second window and not the first non-admin one ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel after I run the script, a UAC window pops up. I click "Yes" to allow the the elevation and then the program gives me an error. I feel like you are on to something but I never see a second cmd window. Also, I am using the IDLE GUI if that makes any difference.