# Run python script as admin

Tags: python, admin, hosts

I have the following code:

```
import re
import os
import fileinput


textToSearch = ('127.16.129.')

print ("Your IP Address:")
textToReplace = input('127.16.129.' + "> " )

fileToSearch = "C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts"

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input(fileToSearch, inplace=True):
    print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace))

tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()


input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

I'm trying to change the IP address in my hosts file to use on my VMWare machine, this has to be done due to roaming profiles and changing computers quite a bit so this script will make it easier to change the IP address in the hosts file.

When I run this script I get the error "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied".
I have administrator rights I just need to be able to run the script as admin.
I am also running on a Windows environment.

Comment: try sudo python script.py if you use Linux based system, using windows you can try open as admin.

Comment: @zoosuck sudo on window ?. coult try to run a terminal as administrator

Comment: Using cmd on windows as admin gives me the error that the file is open in another program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilage-on-windows