# Create executable that uses admin rights with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I need to create an executable for windows 8.1 and lower, so I tried Py2Exe (no success) and then PyInstaller, and damn it, it worked.
Now I need to run it as admin (everytime since that uses admin tasks).
My actual compiling script looks like this : 
`python pyinstaller.py --onefile --noconsole --icon=C:\Python27\my_distrib\ico_name --name=app_name C:\Python27\my_distrib\script.py`
Is there an option to use UAC or things like this ? (its mess to me)

Also, everytime I start it on my laptop windows 8.1 (my desktop computer is windows 7) it says that is dangerous... Anything to make it a "trust" exe?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the trust level is more tied to the location rather than the application itself.  And to get an application to request admin rights, you need to add a manifest that specifies it or rename your app to "setup.exe".

Answer (score 24):

PyInstaller 3.0 includes the `--uac-admin` option!

Answer (score 0):

If you want more direct control over when the program asks for admin privileges, or if you don't want to rely on PyInstaller, you can use [the PyUAC module](https://pypi.org/project/pyuac/) (for Windows). Install it using:

```
pip install pyuac
pip install pypiwin32
```

Direct usage of the package is:

```py
import pyuac

def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        print("Re-launching as admin!")
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
    else:        
        main()  # Already an admin here.
```

Or, if you wish to use the decorator:

```py
from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin
def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can then use your PyInstaller command without the UAC option.

(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719292/16136190))