# pass password to Admin prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a script which needs to run a command on command line with admin privileges.

```
password = "abcdef"
cmd = ['runas', '/user:', 'cmd.exe /C echo test']
cmd[1]+=str(platform.node())
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

I can have the code get to ask for password(admin password), but is there a way I can supply password without it asking me again and again as there a quiet a number of times I need to call command line

Comment: http://www.guidingtech.com/4862/always-run-as-administrator/

Comment: @user1767754 i can do it on my pc but what if I want to distribute this piece of code and there are people out there who don't know to change name of file

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows