# Copy files to sytem folder in windows using python

Tags: python, windows

I have to copy dll files to C:\Windows\System32 folder. I get permission denied error. Is there some way to do that other than running the script as administrator?

This did not work:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil 
import win32com.shell.shell as shell 

ASADMIN = 'asadmin' 

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN: 
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]) 
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN]) 
    print "params : ", params, " script : ", script
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', 
                         lpFile=sys.executable, 
                         lpParameters=params) 

print "I am root now." 
nvcudadll = "C:\\Users\\alankritag\\Desktop\\abc.dll" 
winpath = os.environ['WINDIR'] + "\\System32"
shutil.copyfile(nvcudadll, winpath)
```

Comment: I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows) when I had your problem. Does this help you as well?

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra I also tried that example. I only changed value of params in that code as path of my script.


My script is: 
    #!/usr/bin/python
import shutil,os

 
def main():

    nvcudadll = "C:\\Users\\alankritag\\Desktop\\xyz.dll"
    winpath = os.environ['WINDIR'] + "\System32"
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(nvcudadll,winpath)
    except IOError,err:
         print err

    if __name__ == main():
         main()

Comment: Only `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller`, and `BUILTIN\Administrators` can modify the "System32" directory. Your access token needs to have one of these SIDs enabled. If not, elevate to administrator via `ShellExecute` "runas". You only need ctypes for this; you don't have to install PyWin32.

Comment: @eryksun 
This  did not work : 

 import os
import sys,shutil
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    print "parrams : ",params," script : ",script
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    print "I am root now."
    nvcudadll = "C:\\Users\\alankritag\\Desktop\\abc.dll"
    winpath = os.environ['WINDIR'] + "\System32"
    shutil.copyfile(nvcudadll,winpath)