# Permission error in Google Cloud Text To Speech - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am building a chatbot using python, Anaconda with VS Code editor. I am using google cloud for text to speech and its working fine unless I ask it a question, for which it has to execute `if "mean" in text`, it says `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Programming\\python\\thief.mp3'`.

**Note: For rest of the elif statements, (which I didn't show here), it works like a charm and responds perfectly in speech, which makes this question not a duplicate of any other question.**

A snippet of code:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()
bannedWord=["what","does","mean"]
from google.cloud import texttospeech
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-US',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

class commander:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def discover(self,text):
        if "mean" in text:
            x=' '.join(i for i in text.split() if i not in bannedWord)
            print(x)
            #noun=dictionary.meaning(x)["Noun"]
            noun=dictionary.meaning(x)
            if noun["Noun"]:
                for count,ele in enumerate(noun["Noun"]):
                    self.respond(ele)
            elif noun["Verb"]:
                for count,ele in enumerate(noun["Verb"]):
                    self.respond(ele)
            elif noun["Adjective"]:
                for count,ele in enumerate(noun["Adjective"]):
                    self.respond(ele)
            elif noun["Adverb"]:
                for count,ele in enumerate(noun["Adverb"]):
                    self.respond(ele)
    def respond(self,response):
        print(response)
        synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=response)
        response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)
        with open(r'D:\Programming\python\thief.mp3', 'wb') as out:
            out.write(response.audio_content)
            print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
        music.load(r"D:\Programming\python\thief.mp3")
        music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: You don't have permissions to open the `thief.mp3` file. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: @Dustin As I said dustin, it is not giving permission error on the rest of elif statements. Therefore its not a duplicate.

Comment: Reboot your machine. If a previous process still has a file handle open, you can receive this error.

Comment: @MuhammadRamish Can you show us the rest of the elif statements then?

Comment: Could be that? A previous process with this exactly file? Did you tried what John suggested?