# Pandas df export to csv: No permission

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to save dataframe to csv file. However, I kept getting error that I dont have the permission to save my dataframe to the path.

Below is the loop that I have to iterate my object

```
for i in dic:
   dic[i].df.to_csv(Path)
```

> PermissionError:[Errno13] Permission denied: Path

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469464/8353711)

Comment: The OS is telling you that you don't have write permission to that file or directory. Are you able to save and edit files there not through the script?

Comment: The obvious answer is that `Path` is a file/directory that you don't have permission to write to.  Have you checked that?