# Open directory and read distinct files and save them into distinct variables, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with this list of files in a local directory:

```
docs = ['5d7d3c905deeb7978034cb40.txt','5d7d3c905deeb7978034cb40.txt','5d7d26ae5deeb7978034cab3.txt',
        '5d7d268e5deeb7978034cab2.txt','5dac3ad15deeb749fcbbfeab.txt']
```

If I do this:

```
for doc in docs:

   for txt in open(doc):
```

I manage to open and read the texts all together. But I want to get each one of them into a distinct variable.

My best solution, for now, is this one:

```
abstracts = []

for i in range(len(docs)):

   for doc in docs:

      for txt in open(doc):

          txs = [txt] #each text 

          if txs not in abstracts:
             abstracts.append(txs)
```

I can reach the txs I want by the use of indexes, but I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Use a dict with the file names as keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: @snakecharmerb.  It's not as simple as a matter of creating a number of variables, it goes with a specfific task. In this case openning several files in a directory at the same time and being able to make them differ in some way (variable names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary which the keys are the files' names and and values are the files' content

```py
files = {}
for doc in docs:
    with open(doc, 'r') as f:
        files[doc] = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead use a `dict` in python.

```
import os

content_dict = {}

for f_name in os.listdir("."):
    content_dict[f_name.split(".")[0]] = open(f_name).read()

print(content_dict)
```

Comment: I've got this error, trying the code: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.git'

Comment: Either remove the `.git` repo by doing `rm -rf .git` or follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied Or run the script as admin

Comment: He already has the files names.. he didn't ask for a solution of getting a dict of files from a directory..

Comment: I suggested him a better way to the same job @kakigadol

Comment: You suggested him a way for a similar but different job.. If we didn't post our answers in about the same time I would have just edit your answer but NVM..
btw I would suggest `pathlib.Path.iterdir()` instead of `os.listdir()`

Answer (score 0):

`globals()["name_of_your_variable"] = my_variable` will assign a variable based on the string you give it. It should work if you `str.split(doc, ".")[0]` it first to remove the period.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how could I use your suggestion to solve my problem? Thank you