# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied as Administrator

Tags: python, windows, permission-denied

I am trying to save a csv file with pandas but keep getting this error with this code:

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({
        "PassengerId": test_data["PassengerId"],
        "Survived": y_pred })

submission.to_csv(r"C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Bureau", index=False)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1b9e56f25017> in <module>
      4         "Survived": y_pred })
      5 
----> 6 submission.to_csv(r"C:\Users\thoma\OneDrive\Bureau", index=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
   3021 
   3022         if path_or_buf is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    155             f, handles = _get_handle(self.path_or_buf, self.mode,
    156                                      encoding=self.encoding,
--> 157                                      compression=self.compression)
    158             close = True
    159 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    422         elif encoding:
    423             # Python 3 and encoding
--> 424             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    425         elif is_text:
    426             # Python 3 and no explicit encoding

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\thoma\\OneDrive\\Bureau'
```

I am just starting learning Python: does anyone have any idea? I am running Windows as Administrator.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36434764/1025391

Comment: Is "Bureau" a file name, or a directory name? You need to add the name of the file (including .csv) to the end of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Is your corresponding .csv open while you are trying to modify it?
In some instances, files cannot be modified while they are used by other programs (e.g. Excel).