# Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv

Tags: ubuntu, youtube-dl

I was trying to download from the youtube

```
youtube-dl -F 249 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXT1ElMEkW8"
```

My version `youtube-dl --version` 2019.11.28

I went throgh the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/806258/requested-formats-are-incompatible-for-merge but could not help to resolve the issue

[youtube] yXT1ElMEkW8: Downloading webpage [youtube] yXT1ElMEkW8: Downloading video info webpage WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv. ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '1.6 - Cloning Repo and Push_Pull - Git and GitHub for Poets-yXT1ElMEkW8.f247.webm.part'

Answer (score 0):

Everything about this is basically normal except for:

> ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied

However, that's unlikely to be an issue with `youtube-dl`; instead you were probably trying to write to a directory you / your shell didn't have write access to. In CMD / Powershell try navigating to something like downloads & rerun your command:

```
cd "C:\Users\<YOUR USER FOLDER>\Downloads"
```

You may then need to run `youtube-dl` with:

```
"<youtube-dl-path>\youtube-dl.exe" -F 249 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXT1ElMEkW8"
```

Alternatively, open your CMD / Powershell instance with administrative privileges (if you know what you're doing): [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/36469464)