# How do i copy files to a read-only folder in python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I understand that I need to use
`shutil.copyfile()` but I keep getting an error when actually trying to copy a file to said read-only folder. I tried turning off read-only manually at the folder but it just turns itself back on.

`Error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied: [long folder path]`

I also tried running as administrator but that did nothing.

Also note that I am using a windows 11 pc

Edit: I have also tried using `os.system("attrib -r " + path)`
which led to the same exact error.

Comment: "it just turns itself back on" - how? Did turning off the read-only mode work for a moment?

Comment: How was the folder created? Windows sometimes has weird permissions issues when I `rsync` a folder from linux to my windows pc.

Comment: @lucidbrot The parent folder is AppData and my current theory on why it's turning itself back on is that AppData has read-only set to itself and all children files/folders. edit: oh and no it didn't work for a moment. I checked on and then looked at the property's and it changed pretty much right away.

Comment: @lucidbrot the folder was created when I installed minecraft Java edition. The folder im trying to copy files to is .minecraft/mods

Comment: I have no idea how windows permissions for that folder works, but it looks like [you are not the only one with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839646/how-to-give-python-permission-to-copy-files-in-appdata). A quick google on my part did not reveal exactly how to get appdata permission in another program's folder. Before you dive too dep into windows permissions though: Could it be that you specified the path wrong, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244490/2550406) ?

Comment: @lucidbrot I don't think I've got the path wrong but it is worth looking into so I will check to make sure that's not the case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

## Found an answer!

As it turns out, after lots and lots of research, every folder for windows has that read-only box toggled but it doesn't actually do anything. Weird huh? So that wasn't really the issue. The actual issue had something to do with the
`shutil.copyfile()` method. If you use `shutil.copy2()` it will work. Not sure why though. Couldn't get an explanation on that.

Comment: Interesting. You can view the differences [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). Does a `copy` work too? One thing I notice is that `copy` and `copy2` support `dst` being a directory instead of file path. If you specified a folder, then that was the problem. They also retain the original file permissions and [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) is a note that says on windows that is just the file's readonly flag. Perhaps this is important when moving to a readonly folder (?) that might otherwise propagate the readonly to the file (?)

Comment: Well... looks like `copy2` is a strict superset of `copyfile`, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/shutil.py#L421). So it must have been that you used a folder path instead of a file path. Can you confirm?