# How do I resolve a permission error in pandas trying to read a local json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read in a json file I have saved locally on my computer into a jupyter notebook. I keep receiving a permission error. I've checked `Properties > Sharing` and all accounts have full permission. In `General` I removed the `read-only` attribute.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf="NY/2021-2022_General_Assembly/bill")
```

I get the following error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'NY/2021-2022_General_Assembly/bill'`

I'm using Windows 10. The json files I'm trying to import are in a directory several levels lower than where the notebook is housed.

Comment: maybe this can help: [PermissionError:(Errno 13)Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)