# How to copy a folder with Python and paste it elsewhere?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to select a folder and then copy it and paste it somewhere, I did this with the `tkinter` and `shutil` module in **Python**.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import shutil

window = Tk()
window.title("copyfolder")
window.geometry("210x50")

folderPath = StringVar()
def select_folder():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folderPath.set(folder_selected)
    folder = folderPath.get()
    shutil.copy2(folder, "/data")
    print("Complate")

Button(window,text="select",command=select_folder).place(x=80,y=10)

window.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/Myfolder'`

Comment: `shutil.copytree()` from the `shutil` module can solve you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

As given by this link, this happens if you are trying to open a file, but your path is a folder.

As the comments state, use:

```
shutil.copytree()
```