# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on mac

Tags: python

When I try to run the code below, the mac refuse the connection.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        message = "Welcome to COE 550!"
        self.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Length",len(message))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return

server = ('localhost', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server, RequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The output message is

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: The PermissionError: [errno 13] permission denied error occurs when you try to access a file from Python without having the necessary permissions. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port `80` is considered as privileged port([TCP/IP port numbers below 1024](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)) so the process using them must be owned by root.  When you run a server as a test from a non-priviliged account, you have to   test it on other ports, such as [2784, 5000, 8001 or 8080](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html).

You could either run the *python process as root* or you have to use any *non privileged port* to fix this issue.

```
server = ('localhost', 8001)
httpd = HTTPServer(server, RequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```