# Permission denied in the code I have created trained folder in dataset folder

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection

I'm getting a `permission denied` on my code.

There is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Acadamic studies\Major Project\facetrain.py", line 24, in <module>
    faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
  File "E:\Acadamic studies\Major Project\facetrain.py", line 15, in getImagesAndLabels
    PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # grayscale
  File "C:\Users\Sonu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2968, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:/Acadamic studies/Major Project/dataset\\trainer'
```

Comment: Add a code snippet or something similar to reproduce this issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  Without any code we can only guess why you are getting the error.  As mentioned above see [PermissionError: `[`Errno 13`]` Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied) for general help with this error.