# pyhon os module permission error. when i set splitted pdf output in their name folder it gives an error [permission denied ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

this pdf splitter program I want to do some modifications in this like when I give any pdf to split it creates the folder by that pdf name and store all pdf in that folder.. when I try to do that, the program gives an error [permission denied ]. please help me !!

````
    ** This is my code **
    
    # pdf_splitter.py
    
    import os
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
    
    
    def pdf_splitter(path):
        fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    
        pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
        for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
            pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
    
            output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
                fname, page+1)
    
            with open(output_filename, 'w') as out:
                pdf_writer.write(out)
    
            print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        path = input("Enter Path : ")
        foldername=path.split('.')[0]
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        try:
            os.mkdir(foldername)
        except:
            pass
        outputpath = os.path.join(cwd,foldername)
        pdf_splitter(outputpath)
    
    
    **I got this error**
    
    
    ``` 
    
    
    PS D:\Downloads\pdf> & C:/Python310/python.exe d:/Downloads/pdf/pdf.py
    Enter Path : demo.pdf
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\Downloads\pdf\pdf.py", line 40, in <module>
        pdf_splitter(outputpath)
      File "d:\Downloads\pdf\pdf.py", line 10, in pdf_splitter
        pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1081, in __init__
        fileobj = open(stream, 'rb')
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Downloads\\pdf\\demo'
````

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36434764/13552470

Comment: Why do you remove the extension from the filename?  `PdfFileReader` expects to get a PDF file name.  You're not passing that.

Comment: because I want to create an output folder from the pdf name..