# Building cassandra-website with docker yields a python3 permissions error

Tags: python, docker, cassandra

I am trying to build https://github.com/apache/cassandra-website

Python3 is installed, I started the docker daemon, git pull and then run `./run.sh website preview` but it yields the following permissions issue even though I am running as root.

```
[root@localhost cassandra-website]# ./run.sh website preview
Server Docker Engine version: 1.13.1

Executing docker command:
docker run --rm --name website_content -p 5151:5151/tcp -v /root/cassandra-website:/home/build/cassandra-website -v /root/cassandra-website/site-ui/build/ui-bundle.zip:/home/build/ui-bundle.zip  -e ANTORA_CONTENT_SOURCES_CASSANDRA_WEBSITE_URL=/home/build/cassandra-website -e ANTORA_UI_BUNDLE_URL=/home/build/ui-bundle.zip apache/cassandra-website:latest  preview
container: INFO: Entering preview mode!
container: INFO: Building site.yaml
python3: can't open file './bin/site_yaml_generator.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: I am not sure this is Cassandra related. Maybe something related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)?

Comment: First problem is that ./bin directory isn't created. I tried creating the directory and running touch site_yaml_generator.py to see if I could move forward in the error but it still gets a permission denied.

Comment: I tried updating to latest docker according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/ now yield a new error: 

container: INFO: Building site.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/site_yaml_generator.py", line 158, in <module>
    site_yaml.generate_file()
  File "./bin/site_yaml_generator.py", line 57, in generate_file
    ).dump("site.yaml")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1603                                            , in dump
    fp = open(fp, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'site.yaml'

Comment: I also installed every python3 dependency under the sun and still no luck. Looks like a bug in the docker package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

1. Update to latest docker from docker official repo
2. Update python3 and install yum install -y python36*
3. Make sure apache ant is installed (which explains the yaml issue)
4. Run docs build target
5. Run preview build target
   Access 127.0.0.7:port/path/to/docs and Voila