# Have a problem. PermissionError: [Errno 13] Default\Cache\Cache_Data\data_0 (PROGRAM WAS RUNNING WITH ADMIN ACCESS)

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I was making script, that will upload to dropbox zip file with folder Default, path: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.
The error was:
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/umnJ3.jpg
My code is:

```
    HO = zipfile.ZipFile('huilo.zip', 'w')
    os.chdir('C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
        for file in files:
            HO.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    HO.close()
    global dbx
    access_token = 'access token'
    ssss = os.path.join('C:\Users\user/Desktop/huilo.zip')
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)
    with open(ssss, 'r') as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/w/huilo.zip',  mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"), autorename=False, mute = True)
    sdss = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(path = '/w/huilo.zip', short_url=False, pending_upload=None)
    o = str(sdss.url)
    my = open('C:\Users\user/Desktop/sho.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8')
    my.write(o)
    my.close()
```

Comment: Is the file you're attempting to write actually a folder? This will appear as a permission denied error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: @NickODell yes, the path is: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default. I want to zipfile this folder with files, and upload to dropbox.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Tell me, does the traceback in the error show you a valid path?

Comment: @nigel239 I think yes, because i'm doing zip file with whole folder Default
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: @nigel239 as you can see:
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
        for file in files:
            HO.write(os.path.join(root, file))
root: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
file: \Default. I think the error is that the program cannot write the file "data_... in path: /Default/Cache\Cache_Data\data_...\" to zipfile

Comment: @nigel239 Yes, because the folder is created on the desktop, for some reason. You can see code

Comment: @nigel239 HO = zipfile.ZipFile('huilo.zip', 'w')
    
***os.chdir('C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')***

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):

        for file in files:

            HO.write(os.path.join(root, file))

    HO.close()

Comment: Python's backslash is an escape character. It has special meaning. Try this: `os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')`. Pick one of the two. Or forward slashes, or backward slashes. Not both for paths.

Comment: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-create-a-zip-archive-from-multiple-files-or-directory/ Second block here shows you how to do it.

Comment: @nigel239 Hi, this is not working, the error is saying, that program can't read file without extension in path /Default/Cache\Cache_Data\data_...\.

Comment: Did I say you should use that? My friend, look at your image. I cannot make more of the path.

Comment: @nigel239 sorry..

Comment: @nigel239 I FOUND SOLUTION
The error was in

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
    for file in files:
        HO.write(os.path.join(root, file))
Only what i need to do, it's a change root to subdir Correct code:

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
    for file in files:
        HO.write(os.path.join(subdir, file))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
    for file in files:
        HO.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Only what i need to do, it's a change root to subdir
Correct code:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('Default/'):
    for file in files:
        HO.write(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```