# Writing a one liner code that outputs filenames with more than 10 characters and whose content has more than 10 lines

Tags: python, filenames, listdir

Thank you all for the help before. I now had completed a task (so I thought) in order to achieve the following: I needed to write a one liner which outputs filenames that have more than 10 characters and also their contents consists out of more than 10 lines. My code is the following:

```
import os; [filename for filename in os.listdir(".") if len(filename) > 10 and len([line for line in open(filename)]) > 10 if filename =! filename.endswith(".ipynb_checkpoints")]
```

The problem that exists is the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '.ipynb_checkpoints'
```

I tried to exclude the .ipynb_checkpoint-files but it still doesn´t work properly. Do you have any suggestions on how to exclude them or solve my problem? Thank you for your time!

Greetings.

Comment: "write a one-liner in Python" seems to me to completely miss the point of Pythonic style. Just sayin'.

Comment: Well that was my university task:(

Comment: Why on earth would a university teach you this?

Comment: I totaly agree with you, I just wanna finish with this and move on with better coding classes :) That is my last taskd sheet

Comment: Although maybe Stack Overflow should get the diploma then ;-)

Comment: @alxnom334: ok, check out [`os.access`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20access#os.access). But read the note in the documentation about the check-before-use race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be the order of your if statements, `String.ends` with returns a boolean and cannot be compared to the string, and `__pycache__` files also cause errors so I added it.

Some of the characters in ipynb files cause `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode` errors and decoding in `Latin-1` seemed to fix that. ([UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character))

you could try something like:

```
import os; print([filename for filename in os.listdir(".") if not filename.endswith(".ipynb_checkpoints") and not filename.endswith("__pycache__") and len(filename) > 10 and len([line for line in open(filename, encoding="Latin-1")]) > 10])
```

this solution seems to work but maybe a more general solution makes more sense.ie: [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434764/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied)