# how to copy and remove all the files in a list of drives and all directories and subdirectories in each drive in the list using python?

Tags: python

I wrote this program:

```
import os
import shutil

folder = "e:/folder"
count = 0

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)

# Define the list of supported formats
supported_formats = [
    "JPEG",
    "GIF",
    "PNG",
    "TIFF",
    "BMP",
    "PDF",
    "RAW",
    "PSD",
    "EPS",
    "SVG",
    "WebP",
    "HEIF",
    "ICO",
    "WMF",
    "EMF",
    "EXIF",
    "PPM",
    "PGM",
    "PBM",
    "CR",
    "CR2",
    "ERF",
    "NEF",
    "NRW",
    "ORF",
    "PEF",
    "RW2",
    "ARW",
    "SRF",
    "SR2",
    "DDS",
    "TGA",
    "HDR",
    "PCX",
    "PICT",
    "JP2",
    "JXR",
    "J2K",
    "JPM",
    "JBIG",
    "JNG",
    "MNG",
    "WBMP",
    "XBM",
    "XPM",
    "DNG",
    "HEIC",
    "AVIF",
    "WIM",
    "SGI",
    "CR3",
    "RAF",
    "MRW",
    "DCR",
    "MOS",
    "RWL",
    "BMP",
    "GIF",
    "PSD",
    "AI",
    "EPS",
    "SVG",
    "WebP",
    "HEIF",
    "ICO",
    "WMF",
    "EMF",
    "EXIF",
    "PPM",
    "PGM",
    "PBM",
    "CR",
    "CR2",
    "ERF",
    "NEF",
    "NRW",
    "ORF",
    "PEF",
    "RW2",
    "ARW",
    "SRF",
    "SR2",
    "DDS",
    "TGA",
    "HDR",
    "PCX",
    "PICT",
    "JP2",
    "JXR",
    "J2K",
    "JPM",
    "JBIG",
    "JNG",
    "MNG",
    "WBMP",
    "XBM",
    "XPM",
    "DNG",
    "HEIC",
    "AVIF",
]

# Get a list of all supported files in the C D E F drives
supported_files = []
for drive in ["C:/", "D:/", "E:/", "F:/"]:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        for file in files:
            for format in supported_formats:
                if file.upper().endswith(f".{format}"):
                    supported_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

# Copy all supported files to the specified folder
for file in supported_files:
    shutil.copy(file, folder)
    count += 1
    print(f"{count} : [*] file {file} copied !")
    os.remove(file)

# Wait for user input before exiting
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

this program finds all the files with the format that there is in supported_formats list and copy them to specified folder but this program has some issues that I want to get help to solve them the first one is when I execute this code I got this error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'e:/folder\Bonjour.ico' at the end and the second issue is I want to delete the files from original source after copying them but the program does not work like that I want. (I should mention that I ran the program with administrator privileges). please help.

I just want to find a way to solve these issues

Comment: By googling the error it seems that the issue is you are trying to access different user files. This should help you run the code with administrator [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469464/16008501)