# How do i get python to read my excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read information from my Excel file but continue to run into the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'OptionsBook.xlsx'.

I have tried both `pandas` and `openpyxl` to do this but both lead to the same error.

In my code I have also tried iterating through my files to see if python even recognizes the file but I know that it does.

Here is my current snippet of code that I am using:

```py
file = os.listdir('C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/Desktop')
for f in file:
    print(f)
dataframe = xl.load_workbook("OptionsBook.xlsx")
dataframe1 = dataframe.active
```

Whenever I do that I do end up seeing all of the files on my desktop and the OptionsBook is one of them.

But ultimately whenever I try one of the many tricks to read the Excel file it errors saying that there is no such directory or file.

**Is there a problem with OneDrive or am I missing something else?**

Comment: Include the path to the file in the string that represents the file name: `xl.load_workbook("C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/OptionsBook.xlsx")`

Comment: You could also change the current working directory before reading the file: `os.chdir(C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/Desktop')`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:
`dataframe = xl.load_workbook("OptionsBook.xlsx")`

Even though you've traversed the `C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/Desktop` path before that line, that doesn't mean you're in that directory now.

The piece of code you did before, found that file because you've used the whole path, but now when you're opening, you're not putting the complete path, so you can't open the file.

So just change it to use the full path:

```
dataframe = xl.load_workbook("C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/Desktop/OptionsBook.xlsx")
```

Another solution, as commented by @sj95126, instead of using the whole path you could change your current directory, and then, only use the file name.

```
os.chdir("C:/Users/DUMMY/OneDrive/Desktop")
dataframe = xl.load_workbook("OptionsBook.xlsx")
```

Comment: that seemed to solve my issue with my file not being detected. Now i am trying to resolve the issue where I get the error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'OptionsBook.xlsx

Comment: I would take a step back and, first make the path a raw string, and also verify the whole path you're giving is indeed a file. Take a look at this answer here and try to reproduce it https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244490/5005360