# Digits and caffe on windows error 5

Tags: python, caffe, digits

I am trying to create a classification model using digits GUI 3.0. and I am getting this error:

> **ERROR: [Error 5] Access is denied**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\DIGITS\digits\scheduler.py", line 494, in run_task
>       task.run(resources)   File "C:\DIGITS\digits\task.py", line 208, in run
>       env=env,   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py",
>   line 534, in **init**
>       reraise(*exc_info)   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py",
>   line 503, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py",
>   line 847, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

I could create the data set correctly. However, creating the model is triggering that error.

Comment: Use some `socket` objects with default setting ! Mean which  port binding for you ? An additional  question : "how to access resource without root users ?"

Comment: @dsgdfg "Use some socket objects with default setting ! " May you please give some hints here.. I have administrator privileges

Comment: On `..\gevent\subprocess.py` Line 791 : `def _find_w9xpopen(self):` found `"w9xpopen.exe"`  but haven't permission for running it. (`import admin ; if not admin.isUserAdmin():  admin.runAsAdmin();`) here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows