# How can i run Jupyter notebook in admin privilege?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

### Because of API I need to run Python with admin privileges.

I can run Anaconda or PyCharm with admin privileges by click running by admin privilege.

But how can I run Python on Jupyter notebook with admin privileges?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a script with elevated privilege on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896638/how-to-run-a-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are in a Windows environment.

You can run `cmd` with admin privilege then run `jupyter notebook`.

1. Type `cmd` in the start menu
2. Right click on `Command Prompt` and click `Run as administrator`
3. Type `jupyter notebook` in `cmd` and press enter

Please use this with caution as admin privilege is not something you want to use for every automation.

Comment: when I type ``jupyter notebook`` on cmd it says ``'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.``. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed or Added Jupyter Notebook or the Anaconda bundle as a PATH environment variable, you can access Jupyter Notebook as a executable file. Therefore, Search: Jupyter Notebook --> Right click, Run as Administrator.

Now that you have admin access, you can modify/update package installer functions such as 'pip' from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).