# PyInstaller UAC not working in onefile mode

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Hello everybody.

I have a small python project and want to make it to **single executable file**. I am using...

- Windows 7
- Python 3.4
- PyInstaller 3.2.1

My PyInstaller command is,

```
PyInstaller -y -w -F -n output_file_name --uac-admin --clean source_file.py
```

this command works properly. But single output file does not ask for admin rights when executed. And there's no shield mark on executable file icon.

When **remove the -F option** (equivalent to --onefile), output executable file has shield mark on its icon and ask me admin rights. But this is not what I want. I want a single executable file.

I found a manifest file (output_file_name.exe.manifest) in dist\output_file_name folder. So I did...

```
PyInstaller -y -w -F -n output_file_name --manifest output_file_name.exe.manifest --uac-admin --clean source_file.py
```

But this command doesn't work. Its single executable file still does not ask for admin rights.

I have removed PyInstaller and installed recent development version.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git@develop
```

But the result is same. Its output doesn't have a shield mark on icon and does not ask admin rights.

Do you have any idea?

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

I found what's wrong!

The key point is...

1. Install PyInstaller 3.0
2. Manifest file must be located in **dist** folder where single excutable file located
3. The name of manifest file must be same as output file.
4. If manifest file is located in dist folder, no need to specify --manifest option. --uac-admin is enough.
5. You can find manifest file at **build** folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Same here: `--manifest` does not work, but when you omit that and put the manifest file in the same folder as the executable, admin permissions are requested.

Comment: Btw this was in both pyinstaller and 3.2.1 and 3.3.1.

Comment: ensure you use the `--uac-admin` flag on the console, else the manifest file will not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! It saves my day. What a silly bug it is.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up [passion053's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082998/7755797) answer, in my case I used `-F` instead of `--onefile` and it works fine for me but yeah you need to add `manifest` file in the same directory as your single executable.

**Note**: I used `pyinstaller` version `3.5`. and it works fine for my

**Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-r prog.exe.manifest,1` to `pyinstaller` command line worked for me, after that no need for putting manifest file near exe, pure single exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more direct control over when the program asks for admin privileges, or if you don't want to rely on PyInstaller, you can use [the PyUAC module](https://pypi.org/project/pyuac/) (for Windows). Install it using:

```
pip install pyuac
pip install pypiwin32
```

Direct usage of the package is:

```py
import pyuac

def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        print("Re-launching as admin!")
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
    else:        
        main()  # Already an admin here.
```

Or, if you wish to use the decorator:

```py
from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin
def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can then use your PyInstaller command without the UAC option.

(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719292/16136190))