# netstat -nb in python powershell

Tags: python, powershell

Could someone help me find how to run `netstat -nb` in powershell script in python?

```
import os
def main():
     a = os.popen('netstat -nb').read()
     print ("\n Connections", a)
main()
```

Output:

> The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: run with administrator priveleges

Comment: how can i run it from the cmd with administrator priveleges

Comment: Right-click the executable and choose `Run as administrator`.

Comment: Or invoke the script from an already elevated PowerShell instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run python script with elevated privilege on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you need to activate the power shell as administrator