# Run process as admin with subprocess.run in python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, admin

Is there a way of passing some `runas=True` arg to a `subprocess.run` function in python? I want to run a process as admin (elevate it). Thanks for answers :)\

EDIT: Using Windows OS.

Answer (score 23):

Windows has a command line utility "Run as", which can be used as

`runas [{/profile | /noprofile}] [/env] [{/netonly | /savecred}] [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user:<UserAccountName> "<ProgramName> <PathToProgramFile>"`

for further reference
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

You can use this in code like below

```
import subprocess as sp

prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```

Comment: Note that this only works with the built-in `Administrator` user account, not generally with users that are part of the `Administrators` group. In practice, the built-in `Administrator` account is often disabled for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a command as the same user but with admin privilege

Please refer to this solution:

```py
os.system(r'''
Powershell -Command "& { Start-Process \"notepad.exe\"
 -ArgumentList @(\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts\")
 -Verb RunAs } " '''
```

The original answer can be found here https://superuser.com/a/753600/1088510

Answer (score 2):

There are three approaches:

1. Using `runas` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385474/934719). The downside of this approach is that it uses the Administrator account instead of the current user's Administrator privileges. This does not work well if you plan to deploy your software to users.
2. Use `ShellExecute` as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows) to start your subprocess. The downside is that you won't be able to work with stdin/stdout/stderr.
3. Use JetBrains' [`WinElevator`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/native/WinElevator) (signed launcher.exe and elevator.exe are available [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/bin/win)). The downside of this approach is that you need to ship two additional ~150kb binaries, the upside is that you can interact with stdin/stdout/stderr.

Answer (score -3):

As others have suggested you can achieve this using powershell.  These are my PS functions I use to elevate to Admin:

```
# ========================================= Admin Rights =======================================================
# Usage: asAdmin $PSCommandPath
function asAdmin
{
    [string]$cmdPath = $args[0]
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$cmdPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
}

#-noexit
function asAdminWithSTA
{
    [string]$cmdPath = $args[0]
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-sta  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$cmdPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the OP was looking for a solution in Python

Comment: @PKCS12 My point was you can call powershell from Python which in turn could run another exe with elevated privileges