# How can I run an application in user mode from an admin account in windows using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, python-requests

I want to run an application in user mode from admin account using python. I tried runas command in subprocess. It is asking for the password. I want to give the password automatically. How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you show us your code ? what you tried sofar, where it goes wrong ... etc...

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo  I have tried something like this "subprocess.Popen('runas /user:user2 <exe path with parameter>')"
This is asking for password. With "/savecred " also I have tried and it asks for the password once. So I can't use this also.

Comment: Similar question has already been answered , with method to pass password programtically
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python/47385474#47385474

Answer (score 0):

With `runas` you do not have the option to give a password for the `runas /user`, and with `/savecred` it will still need the password at least once.

I would like to suggest that you do this through task scheduler, which has a command line interface `schtasks`

Various parameters you can use to specify user and runas user:

`schtasks /Create /?` gives you the help for this feature

You probably want to pay attention to:

`/RU` runas user

`/RP` runas password

Now, you probably don't get any stdout from this process, so ensure you redirect to file which you can read when the process finishes.