# python: Running command line as administrator

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run FreeCAD, a CAD application, through python. 
You can control it through the command line by providing a script (pyhthon) to the executable. 
The problem is that you need administrative privileges to run the .exe file. So what I do in Windows, is the following.

I open CMD as an administrator, and then I type:

```
"C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\FreeCADCmd.exe" -l "C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\cylinder_macro.py"
```

This works! 
However, I am having difficulties making it work from python.I am trying to implement what has been suggested in this post: [Run process as admin with subprocess.run in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python)

```
import subprocess
prog = subprocess.run(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', "C:\\Program Files\\FreeCAD 0.18\\bin\\FreeCADCmd.exe","C:\\Users\\Henry\\Desktop\\cylinder_macro.py"])
```

It does not work.
If I print `prog`, I get:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'C:\\Program Files\\FreeCAD 0.18\\bin\\FreeCADCmd.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Dorian\\Henry\\cylinder_macro.py'], returncode=1)
```

Any ideas of how to get this to work are highly appreciated

Comment: What kind of install do you have that requires admin? I use FreeCAD too, but on Linux

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't know. I just did the standard installation for Windows.