# How to run an exe as admin using os module (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows, admin, launcher, python-os

I want to make an app that launches different exe's but I have a problem, one app requires to run as admin, so my question is how can I run that app as admin from a python script?

Comment: I think you'll need to manually run the script that launches the .exes as admin — otherwise there would be no security because anything could give itself admin privileges. On Windows I think that means using the `runas` command.

Comment: You don't run other processes with `os` (`os.system` is a terrible tool for subprocesses), you use the `subprocess` module. I suspect the answer to your question is in [Python 3: How to use subprocess.run() as admin (windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60214168/364696), but I'm not sure enough to use my badge hammer to dupe to it.

Comment: You can use pywin module to run application with UAC prompt like that: `win32api.ShellExecute(None, 'runas', 'calc', None, None, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the elevate module in python! That worked! Thanks anyway!