# How can i pass a input variable to subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess, user-input, stdin, popen

```py
import subprocess
import sys

password_d=raw_input("Input password")
prog = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:KP\svc','cmd.exe'],universal_newlines=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=sys.stdout)
prog.stdin.write(password_d)
prog.communicate()[0]
```

This is my code. I am trying to login as another user through runas.exe and provide the password through already stored input object password_d which is taken from the user.

When i try to do this it says the password is incorrect. How can i achieve this in python and how can i print what is being fed as input. any leads would really be helpful.

Comment: Look into pexpect: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Are you sure you provide the correct password? According to the answer you seem to be on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python

Comment: I am using the right password.@jpihl.How can i print what is being fed into stdin?

Comment: First, you can print what is being fed into stdin with a `print` statement. Second, if the program is expecting input from stdin, normally that input would be terminated with a '\r\n' sequence, which is missing in your code since `input` does not include that. Try appending that to `password_d` to see if it makes a difference.