# Run jar file as Administrator

Tags: python, jenkins, jar, subprocess, administrator

I am running a jar file from python.
This jar must be run as administrator in order to work.
the python script is run in a jenkins job.
Is there a way to run the jar/python script as and administrator?
either from the jenkins job - or modify the python script.

```
with subprocess.Popen(command,
                      cwd=tool_dir,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                      shell=True) as proc:

    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=1000)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python)?

Comment: Yes - unfortunally this not good for me because I need to be able to use it without password