# How to os.startfile as administrator?

Tags: python

```
import os

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"

os.startfile(path)
```

How can I run this in administrator mode?

Comment: Run the script as the admin user?

Comment: I mean run the path with administrator mode

Comment: @AfterHover what do you mean by *I mean run the path with administrator mode* ?

Comment: `path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"` I want this program to run with administrator rights

Comment: BTW, you have the escape character `\ ` in your string. Either use a raw string `r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"` or use forward slashes `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe"`

Comment: You may also want to check this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/47380378/4046632

Answer (score 0):

With this now the path is executed in admin mode, no?

```
import os

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"

os.startfile(path, 'runas')
```

Comment: If the user has no admin rights they will need to provide admin password. Check my second reference in my second comment

Comment: Ok will keep that in mind thanks

Comment: Just to make it clear - I think your code with `os.startfile(path, 'runas')`  will not work. that is why I said to check the link in the comment