# How to run netstat -nb in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to run netstat -nb via python code but everything I tried gives me the same output, "The requested operation requires elevation."

How do I evaluate  netstat -nb in python?

Comment: It might be helpful to review [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows).

Answer (score 1):

other approach with os module:

```
import os
output_command = os.popen("netstat -nb").readlines()
```

The argument `-b` is only for windows and the error message mean that you need administrator permissions.

Comment: Same output: "The requested operation requires elevation."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['netstat', 'nb'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Comment: I have tried that before, It gives me the same output: "The requested operation requires elevation."

Comment: Are you running it on Windows? If yes, try:

p = Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'netstat','nb'],stdin=PIPE, stdout= PIPE)

p.stdin.write('password')

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

I have not tried this as I am Ubuntu and there the fore worked without asking for sudo.

Another way is to run this command in administrator CMD mode. ;)