# how to run explorer.exe as admin from python

Tags: python, explorer

**background:**

I want to run ESET Internet Security gui file from python as admin. It is named egui.exe. So in it's properties, under compatibility, I checked "run this program as an administrator" check box so it always run's as admin.

Another note is that for some reason that seems to be beyond me if I run this file in python like this:

```
os.startfile("c:\\program files\\ESET\\ESET Security\\egui.exe")
```

or

```
os.system("c:\\program files\\ESET\\ESET Security\\egui.exe")
```

It will freeze and do nothing. i tested the same approach in CMD like these:

```
c:\Program Files\ESET\ESET Security>egui.exe
c:\Program Files\ESET\ESET Security>start egui.exe
```

But both of these will cause CMD to freeze and do nothing and even ctrl + c will not interrupt it and CMD should be closed.

**what I did:**

The approach that somehow works is running the exe file via explorer.exe:

```
os.system('explorer.exe "c:\\program files\\ESET\\ESET Security\\egui.exe"')
```

This will not freeze but the problem is that because I want egui.exe to be run as admin, it will trigger UAC prompt, which is not acceptable because the program is supposed to be a test using GUI Automation.

**Question:**

I can run other programs as admin without triggering UAC prompt when my program itself is run as admin. But I cant when running it via explorer.exe and I think it is because explorer.exe is not as admin itself. So the question is how can I run explorer.exe as admin? Also entering password every time is not acceptable for obvious reasons.

PS: Unfortunately there is no compatibility setting for explorer.exe in its properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run python script with elevated privilege on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)