# Can't copy directories using python's 'shutil' as I doesn't have permission

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to make a file that will back up my files to a directory when I wish for it to (I'm experimenting).

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
import time
import shutil

def backup(systray):
    newPath = shutil.copy(r"D:\Desktop\Random Ass Videos", 'D:\Desktop\Backup File')


menu_options = (("Backup", None, backup),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("RoseBackups.ico", "Rose Backup Tool", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

here is the code above ^^^

but when I run it I get the error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Desktop\\Random Ass Videos'`

I thought it was because the file wasn't run as admin so I tried to add:

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
import time
import shutil

import admin
if not admin.isUserAdmin():
        admin.runAsAdmin()
```

but I got a problem as it couldn't find a module named 'admin' (I'm sure this is 100% my fault as I probably didn't install it correctly)

Any help counts, thanks all!

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the admin module?
I never heard about it and wanted to check the documentation

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719292/469609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not copy folder to folder with shutil.copy
instead use,

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("D:\\Desktop\\Random Ass Videos", 'D:\\Desktop\\Backup File')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the odd thing is I tried this and got the same "permission error" and I thought there was no hope, then when I copy yours it works first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your script by right clicking it and pressing "Run as administrator"

Comment: Can't run it directly as an admin as it doesn't have an option to. good idea though!

Comment: You can start a command prompt as admin: Press ctrl+shift+esc, then go to file->run, type cmd and select "Run as administrator".
Now navigate to where your script is and try running it using "py -3 script_name.py")

Comment: tried that, still get the error ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Desktop\\Random Ass Videos''```