# How to get an admin permission in Python script?

Tags: python, permissions, admin, pyinstaller

I have a code that include a line requires admin permission to run.

`with pydivert.WinDivert("(tcp.DstPort==80   ) and tcp.PayloadLength >0 ") as w:`

When I run the script in cmd without admin rights, I get the next error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied."
```

When I run the script in cmd that opend by "run as administrator", its working.

The problem start when I try to convert this script to exe file by pyinstaller.
The code inside the exe file Requires the admin permissions. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python script with elevated privilege on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the executable as an administrator?

Some programs will let you convert scripts into admin-only executables, but I'm not sure this would help you here. Like I said, try running the EXE as administrator.

Comment: I tried, it’s not working. The exe run as administrator but the code require the permission.