# Kill protected windows process in Python (with admin priviliges?)

Tags: python, admin, kill-process, taskkill

Thank you for reading this!

Firstly, I like to say that I went through a lot of posts, trying lots of different possible solutions and none of them worked, including threads on Stackoverflow.

I need to kill a process that is protected, when I just use the regular os.system(Taskkill /F /IM process.exe), it says "Access Denied".
When I use Taskill in cmd it also gives the same error, nevertheless, all permissions for all users on the process are checked. When I use cmd as admin and I type in the command it kills the process.
So if there's any way to silently (don't open a window ) kill a process in cmd, ran as an admin right  in Python, that would be the solution, or maybe someway without admin priviliges?

Have a good day!

Comment: you could run python as an admin

Comment: So you tried both killing the process WITHOUT elevated privileges with `os.system` in Python as well as with `taskkill` in shell, but not running an elevated python script? I think the answer is obvious.. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)