PermissionError: WinError 5 , cant access msi afterburner app with subprocess
I am trying to create a python script to auto change profiles in my MSI Afterburner, but I am stuck in a PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied error. I have tried to see if its a path/permission problem and its not. I even tried adding the MSI Afterburner path in the system enviromenttal variables but nothing has worked.
import subprocess
import time
    
# Function to switch profiles
def switch_profile(current_profile):
    if current_profile == "1":
        new_profile = "2"
    else:
        new_profile = "1"
    subprocess.run([afterburner_path, f"-Profile{new_profile}"])
    # Add a delay to allow Afterburner to switch profiles
    time.sleep(1)

# Path to MSI Afterburner executable
afterburner_path = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSI Afterburner/MSIAfterburner.exe"'

# Function to get the current profile
def get_current_profile():
    result = subprocess.run([afterburner_path, "-Profile"], capture_output=True, text=True)
    output_lines = result.stdout.strip().split("\n")
    current_profile = output_lines[-1].split(":")[-1].strip()
    return current_profile

# Switch profiles
current_profile = get_current_profile()
switch_profile(current_profile)

This is the error I am getting:
File "c:\Users\iwanh\Desktop\Leetcode\msi-afterburner.py", line 25, in <module>
    current_profile = get_current_profile()
  File "c:\Users\iwanh\Desktop\Leetcode\msi-afterburner.py", line 19, in get_current_profile
    result = subprocess.run([afterburner_path, "-Profile"], capture_output=True, text=True)
  File "C:\Users\iwanh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\iwanh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\iwanh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child       
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied


The program your running requires admin permissions, you need to run your code elevated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows
If this fixes your problem, I could write an answer with the code edited to be elevated.

Yes if possible, but i cant seem to pip install pywin32

Could you give the error you get when you try? You could also just use the given function without the library.

I did manage to pip install pywin32 but now I am getting this Import "win32com.shell.shell" could not be resolved from source

I've added an answer which does not require the pywin32 library, try that and we can debug from there. You shouldn't need to import that.

Your script needs to be run as an administrator to run properly.

import subprocess
import time

def switch_profile(current_profile):
    if current_profile == "1":
        new_profile = "2"
    else:
        new_profile = "1"
    subprocess.run(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', afterburner_path, f"-Profile{new_profile}"])
    # Add a delay to allow Afterburner to switch profiles
    time.sleep(1)

afterburner_path = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSI Afterburner/MSIAfterburner.exe"'

def get_current_profile():
    result = subprocess.run([afterburner_path, "-Profile"], capture_output=True, text=True)
    output_lines = result.stdout.strip().split("\n")
    current_profile = output_lines[-1].split(":")[-1].strip()
    return current_profile

current_profile = get_current_profile()
switch_profile(current_profile)

Your program requires elevated permissions to run. In order to get them on Windows, you can run your subprocess elevated. For more information on what that means, see this answer.

I put missing parenthesis in the prints you gave, but it says raw_input not defined

Try it again, I accidently pasted Python 2 code.

Ok so after I am in the terminal and it says "Press ENTER to exit" then whats the next step

You just press enter in the terminal. If you want it to be fully automatic, you can simply remove the input statements; I will edit the code to reflect this.

I dont see the profile chaning. After I press enter so it can exit i still get "Access denied" error (thats supposed to be like that ??)

Try it once more, I've edited the code so that the subprocess you start (seperate process) uses admin privileges. If that works, I can actually delete a bunch of the other code that elevates the program.

I did copy paste it and I am getting this prompt which i click yes and then it says access is denied again screenshot)

Looking at the documentation for subprocess, the code should work. I'm unsure why it doesn't, and I would need to debug directly rather than through SO before I could get any closer to the solution. I will try to get on a Windows machine later today and give this another shot. Sorry I couldn't help you sooner, hopefully someone else can pitch in and solve this for you in the meantime.
